# PyPlot and Julia can't plot x^2

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I want to plot a simple function, but i can't figured out how to do it.

this code works fine

```
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0,10,1000); y = log(x);
plot(x, y, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
```

but the next code do not work

```
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0,10,1000); y = x^2;

plot(x, y, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
```

i can't figure out how to multiply x by x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an elementwise exponentiation: `x.^2`.

```
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0,10,1000); y = x.^2;

plot(x, y, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
```

In Julia v0.5 and later, you should also use the elementwise version of `log`: `y = log.(x)`. The old automatically-broadcasted functions like `sin`, `log`, etc. are scheduled for deprecation in the v0.6 release cycle.

Comment: Thanks, what is elementwise? is valid do 3.*4'?

Comment: @exsnake The official documentation discusses [elementwise operations](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/mathematical-operations/?highlight=elementwise) briefly. I don't know what you mean by `3.*4'`. That will work, but it seems like an excessively complicated way to write `12`.

Comment: That was just a dumb example. I wanted to mean about use it in variables that are not arrays.

Comment: @exsnake Yes, elementwise operations _generally_ work on scalar values, especially numbers. However, there are non-numeric things like `String`s or `Tuple`s that many elementwise operations will not work well on. (These typically do not support normal operations either, though.)

Answer (score 3):

`Plots.jl` allows a different approach, where you just specify the function to plot and the bounds to plot it in:

```
using Plots

plot(x->x^2, -3, 3)
```

Here, `x->x^2` is an anonymous function. Alternatively, you can define a standard Julia function:

```
f(x) = x^2
plot(f, -3, 3)
```